# Extend Vs Inject in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

EDIT:
After reading the answers it seems that I was confused with the terminology, so basically what im asking is what is the difference between injecting functionality via service and extends functionality via Extends.

Sorry for the confusion!
Thank you.

Comment: can you give some code examples? Because it seems like you are trying to compare apples with... trucks. `extends` extends a base class, and `import`, well it imports an exported module from another file. About `@Injected` there is no such annotation. Just `@Inject()` and `@Injectable()` and they both do not really apply to components, and even it it does, importing it should not matter

Answer (score 0):

Extends and Import are two different things, but can be used together.

**Import** is used to give the origin of a class, method, etc... you are using from another file.

**Extends** allows you to create a specialized version of another class by adding or modifying it's behavior, properties or methods to some extent.

You could very well extend a class from another file, you would then have to import it as well.

**@injected** is used for services, not component, so you can use the same instance through multiple components and share the same instance of a class.

Answer (score 0):

**Import** is you can `import` your libraries and module that have u installed

**Extend** means you can get or `extend` that class properties 
The extends keyword is used to class declarations or class expressions to create a class which is a child of another class that can be used.

> further readings
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 0):

Extends and Imports are two different things. Let's understand both one by one:

**Extends:** The `Extends` keyword is used in class declarations or class expressions to create a class which is a child of another class. See below syntax:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass { ... }
```

*Using extends:* In below example, creates a class called Square from a class called Polygon

```
class Square extends Polygon {
  constructor(length) {
    // Here, it calls the parent class' constructor with lengths
    // provided for the Polygon's width and height
    super(length, length);
    // Note: In derived classes, super() must be called before you
    // can use 'this'. Leaving this out will cause a reference error.
    this.name = 'Square';
  }

  get area() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }
}
```

Example 2: Using extends with built-in objects:

```
class myDate extends Date {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  getFormattedDate() {
    var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    return this.getDate() + '-' + months[this.getMonth()] + '-' + this.getFullYear();
  }
}
```

**Import**: The static import statement is used to import bindings which are exported by another module. Imported modules are in strict mode whether you declare them as such or not.

The syntax of the import module is following. It has so many syntaxes we can say because it is depending on if we are importing a single content or multiple contents from a file.

```
import defaultExport from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { export } from "module-name";
import { export as alias } from "module-name";
import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name";
import { foo , bar } from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file";
import { export1 , export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultExport, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";
var promise = import("module-name");
```

Import an entire module's contents: *This inserts myModule into the current scope, containing all the `exports` from the module in the file located in `/modules/my-module.js`.*

```
import * as myModule from '/modules/my-module.js';
```

Import a single export from a module:

```
import {myExport} from '/modules/my-module.js';
```

Import multiple exports from module:

```
import {foo, bar} from '/modules/my-module.js';
```

Hope this will clear your doubt.